# Specify different database server in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql, database, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, alias

We currently have a SharePoint 2010 farm with one web front-end and one SQL 2005 database server.  We want to move our SharePoint databases to a new SQL 2012 server.  I have gone through Microsoft's recommended method in our dev environment - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723(v=office.14).aspx.

When we originally deployed SharePoint we did not create SQL aliases.  So, now, we have to create an alias for DBServer01 to point to DBServer02.  Now all of my databases are listed as attached to the DBServer01 SQL Instance, but the alias re-directs them to DBServer02.  It works, but I would prefer to set this up a little more elegantly/granular (and I think this is the way it should have been setup to begin with) where each database listed in SharePoint is attached to an Alias name, rather than the DBServer name (so that it can be changed via the SQL Alias in the future, if necessary).

I cannot find a way within Central Admin to change this and was wondering if any one knew of a way to do this via the Management Shell?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are handled at the server Level, not at the database level, you will not be able to assign an alias to one database, and another alias to a second database on the same server. That is a sql limitation.

You can switch the database server your SharePoint installation is on, but there is no granularity for each database/server combination, so I don't think you can have that configuration you ask.

Comment: I understand alias' don't redirect to individual databases, that's not what I'm trying to do.  In Central Administration each database is associated to a "SQL Instance".  I mistakenly set these to be the original DB Server name, when we should have used an alias, instead.  So now my only option is to create an alias for DBServ01 to DVServ02 (the new DB server).  But now I cannot reference DBServ01 for anything from the SP Web front-end (ie using a SQL DB as a datasource for a webpart).  If I could change the "SQL Instance" name within Central Admin I could still use DVServ01 as a datasource.

Comment: Why is your only option to create an alias, Why cant you move the databases to the final location using the stsadm command you linked?